# Update ng-options hosted by a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a custom directive that displays a dropdownlist.

Is it possible to dynamically re-populate the ng-options from a datasource that comes from the controller that hosts the directive.

The datasource itself comes from a service.
Currently it works well from the initial array passed to the directive, but when I add new data (from the controller/service to this array I would like to update the item list.

Any help?

EDIT :

This is how I use my directive.

```
   <select-item-obj-from-array datasource="ctrl.ActivityAddresses" ng-model="form.Activity.AddressID" name="AddressID" value="AddressID" label="City" .... />
```

My directive looks like:

```
app.directive('selectItemObjFromArray', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: function (element, attrs) {
        var tpl = '';
        tpl += "<div><div class=\"form-group clearfix\" >";
        tpl += '<label  for="' + attrs.name + '" class="col-lg-3 control-label">' + attrs.label + '</label>';
        tpl += '<div class="col-lg-9">';
        tpl += '<select ng-disabled="ngDisabled" name="' + attrs.name + '" ng-model="ngModel"   chosen="datasource" ng-options="c.Name for c in datasource"></select>';

        tpl += '</div>';
        tpl += '</div>';
        tpl += '</div>';
        return tpl;
    },
    scope: {
        ngModel: "=",
        datasource: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var select = elem.find("select").eq(0);
        select.chosen();
        scope.$watch(function () {
            return select[0].length;
        },
        function (newvalue, oldvalue) {
            if (newvalue !== oldvalue) {
                select.trigger("chosen:updated");
            }
        });
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {
            select.trigger('chosen:updated');
        });
    }
};
});
```

if  my controller/service updated the ctrl.ActivityAddresses I don't know how to "reinvoke" the directive to update the dropdownlist..

Answer (score 0):

You can broadcast from your service like this:

```
var broadcast = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('items.update');
 };
```

Assuming that items is an array.

Then you can catch the broadcast in your controller or directive:

```
$scope.$on('items.update', function (event) {
    //Do whatever you want with the items.
});
```

I think this is what you want? You don't need to change the ng-options directive for this.